# Electric Turbine Generator using Fan Motor

Tags: generator, windturbine

I need to build a turbine with permanent magnets using a table fan motor, I've come across many tutorials but none of them describes well all the physics on it, it would be appreciated if anyone has experience with this kind of work before, please share the idea.

Explain: Permanent Magnet Synchronous Generator

Comment: You cannot make that much power with a table fan motor, and they are poor candidates for this application.  Please describe your application in detail - energy source, environment, acceptable cost, longevity required, .... . If wind or water or .... Powered there are important issues to consider. || There are various scams showing devices with no energy source. These are invariably fake.

Comment: You need 1000 watts of power? What is the power rating of the fan? (I would guess much less than 1000 watts). There is a good chance that a fan rated for less than 1000 watts will burn up, or otherwise fail, if you try to use it to generate 1000 watts. Maybe you don't really need 1000 watts?

Comment: Table fan motor to give 1000W.  Sorry, no one here would have no experience in making this happen.   It may consume 50W and is a single-phase motor.  Your expectations are unrealistic.

Comment: Can you explain how can we produce 50W at least ?

Comment: Have you considered using an automotive alternator? Some are rated for more than 1000W.

Comment: @Googlian - Hi, Please add some context. You said that you "*need to build a turbine with permanent magnets using a table fan motor.*" Why? Where will the output of the generator be going? You are using a motor, so you already have a source of power. Why use the motor to drive a generator, to generate less power than you put into the motor at the beginning (because of the inevitable losses)? As stated, the project makes no sense, without more info. Please [edit] the question to add that detail. It would also make the question more appealing if you also explain *exactly* where you are stuck. TY

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

The limit on the current you can ge out of a motor or generator is largely set by the amoiunt of iron present in the magnetic path. if you have a 40W 120V motor that's going to be good for about 1/3A.

So to get 1000W from it you'll need to spin it fast enough to generate 3000V
this will probably require upgrading the motor bearings and also possibly replacing the windings with better insulated wire. (or re-doing them for lower voltage and higher current)

You'll almost certainly need to upgrade the fan blades too.